# Python tkinter show text in frame after buttonclick

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

As a Python newbie i am trying to create an application with tkinter. I made a window with a drop down menu. Now, i would like to achieve that when you click a button from the drop down menu, text is being displayed in a frame on the right, or at the bottom. Next, when you press the next button, other text will display in the screen (it will first remove the text from the previous clicked button).

Is it possible for you guys to give me a little piece of code with one Window, a button, and a frame. And once u click the button text is shown in the frame?

Right now i have some code, and once i click on a button a messagebox is opened with the text. But i would like the text to appear in the frame. 
As i think an example can be given with just a few lines of code i will not place my code here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Happy Coding. SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Avoid using screenshots unless you 
need to convey layout errors. We can NOT copy and paste your image into our IDEs to fix your code.

Comment: Sorry, will paste my code next time.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do the job:

```
from tkinter import *

def toggle ():
    global shown
    if shown: l.grid_remove () # Hide the text
    else: l.grid () # Show the text
    shown = not shown # Reverse the 'shown' boolean value

# Create the window with all the widgets contained within a frame
root = Tk ()
f = Frame (root)
f.grid ()
shown = False
Button (f, text = "Toggle text", command = toggle).grid ()
l = Label (f, text = "Your text")
root.mainloop ()
```

Otherwise, does this:

```
from tkinter import *

LIST = ["Something", "Something else"]

root = Tk ()
value = StringVar ()
value.set (LIST [0])
OptionMenu (root, value, *LIST).grid ()
l = Label (root, text = LIST [0])
l.grid ()
value.trace ("w", lambda a, b, c: l.config (text = value.get ()))
root.mainloop ()
```

Comment: Hi Jim, Thanks for your reaction. I will try to edit my code with your examples. It will probably take some time, but it looks good. Thanks again